# How to iterate Xpath in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, apify

I was trying to create a `crawler` for this [page](http://trendset.de/wp-content/themes/trendset/templates/asearch/call_antwort_liste.php?zeigen_start=0&zeigen_end=100&suchtyp=laendersuche&term=DE&term_filter=&_=1488306616468) using [Apifiy](https://www.apify.com/).

Apify uses `jQuery` and css selectors to locate data. But, I cant seem to understand css selectors well, so, I used `XPath`. The code I used only extracted the first row of data, but not the entire list of data.

The code I used is the following:

```
function pageFunction(context) {
    // called on every page the crawler visits, use it to extract data from it
    var $ = context.jQuery;
    var result = {
        ID: document.evaluate('//div[@class="treffer-item"]/@id', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue,
        Title: document.evaluate('//div[@class="treffer-item"]/div[1]/div[1]/span[@class="treffer-inhalt-name"]', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue
    };
    return result;
}
```

How can I iterate this to get entire list of data?

Answer (score 1):

I haven´t tested it, but I would suggest to select all the items first and then use `map` to select the result data. For instance...

```
function pageFunction(context) {

    var $ = context.jQuery;

    var items = $(document).find("//div[@class='treffer-item']");
    var titleSelector = "/div[1]/div[1]/span[@class='treffer-inhalt-name']";

    return items.map(function(item) {
        var id = item.attr("id");
        var title = document.evaluate(
            titleSelector, 
            item, // use current item instead of document 
            null, 
            XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, 
            null).stringValue;
        return { 
            ID: id, 
            Title: title
        };
    });
}
```